# Can't compile jade template

Tags: javascript, pug

I have jade template that throws error (undefined is not a function) at:

```
title=token ? __('Save your card securely') : __('Pay Securely')
```

also at Static():

```
script(src=Static('public/js/main.js'))
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What are `__` and `Static`? Did you copy these off some tutorial? They are not part of Jade or JavaScript.

Comment: I know, I figured. It's not a tutorial. I just need to figure out what dependencies I'm missing.